# subtraction date - how to get result in minutes

Tags: python, datetime

```
t1 = datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 6, 8, 30, 0)
t5 = datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 6, 10, 30, 0)

mytime = t5 - t1
```

How can I get result in minutes?(how many minutes)

Comment: Do you have `datetime` objects or do you have strings?

Comment: I already converted string to datetime object ;) in my code this is date object in this format

Comment: @user2953012 look at `.total_seconds()` on the `mytime` object then...

Comment: To be fair, `total_seconds` wasn't added until python2.7 -- Before that you need to do a little simple math to calculate it (although that math is spelled out pretty clearly in the documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `t1` and `t5` are `datetime.datetime` objects, then subtracting them gives you a [`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) result.

A `timedelta` object deals in days, seconds and microseconds, but with [`timedelta.total_seconds()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) method you can have the number of seconds as a float value. Simply divide by 60 for the minute count:

```
minutes = mytime.total_seconds() // 60
```

If you wanted the remainder seconds as well, use the `divmod()` function:

```
minutes, seconds = divmod(mytime.total_seconds(), 60)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> t1 = datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 6, 8, 30, 0)
>>> t5 = datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 6, 10, 30, 0)
>>> mytime = t5 - t1
>>> mytime
datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)
>>> mytime.total_seconds() // 60
120.0
>>> divmod(mytime.total_seconds(), 60)
(120.0, 0.0)
```

Comment: It's gonna be one of `// 60` or `/ 60` or `mins, secs = divmod(mytime.total_seconds(), 60)` :)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3:

```
mytime_in_minutes = mytime / timedelta(minutes=1)
```

Full example:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> t1 = datetime(2013, 6, 6, 8, 30, 0)
>>> t5 = datetime(2013, 6, 6, 10, 30, 0)
>>> 
>>> mytime = t5 - t1
>>> mytime / timedelta(minutes=1)
120.0
>>> mytime // timedelta(minutes=1)
120
>>> divmod(mytime, timedelta(minutes=1))
(120, datetime.timedelta(0))
```